# maven skip tests with compilation errors

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

Are there an option to skip tests with compilation errors? Just ignore them or treat them as failed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `maven-compiler-plugin` is responsible for compiling your tests during the `test-compile` phase. This plugin is configured to fail the build if any test classes fail to compile. You could experiment with the `failOnError` configuration. But I doubt you'll get the results you expect. The compilation process stops immediately when it encounters a compilation error. So potentially issue free classes may not have been re-compiled. Therefore there will be no guarantee the `.class` files you execute during the `test` phase will be 'up to date' with the corresponding `.java` source files.

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-testCompile</id>
        <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended...

```
mvn -DskipTests=true clean compile
```

Remember, with great power comes great responsibility.

Comment: But that will skip all tests, when I need to skip only tests with compilation errors.

Comment: I haven't tried that before... (now I want to know as well :)) I do know that @Ignore at the top of the method, but that requires a code change.

Comment: Adding @Ignore annotation will not help.

Comment: @Ignore will skip the specific test... I also clarified that it will require a code change and does not work on the command line.  Nothing wrong with my statement.

Comment: How junit @Ignore annotation will help maven compiler plugin to skip test compilation?

Comment: It will skip the test... maven will not run it. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

use the following command to skip the entire test source folder. Through there are compilation errors in the test classes maven wont consider those, if you use the following command.

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Answer (score 0):

`-DskipTests` usually works. For instance, `mvn install -DskipTests`.

If you need to tell maven strictly to ignore - use `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`. This will force all the plugins and compiler to ignore the tests

Edited: Looks like `-DskipTests=true` also works!

Comment: But that will skip all tests, when I need to skip only tests with compilation errors.

Comment: Are you using JUnit tests? Maven can't select tests and ignore them. If you know which tests have compilation failures, using JUnit annotation, @Ignore, for that particular test.

Comment: Adding @Ignore annotation will not help.

Comment: You mean it's not helping? Have you tried it? At some higher level, I wondering why would you want to skip the tests that fail? You are going against the whole concept of testing! You should instead look at why they are failing!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use command line `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`.

Reference: [Maven skipping test](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html)